# django_celery_beat - "no such table: main.django_celery_beat_solarschedule__old" while updating "django_celery_beat_periodictask"

Tags: django, sqlite, celerybeat

I'm using django + celery, when running django devserver I'm getting exception

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.django_celery_beat_solarschedule__old`

and callstack tells that it occured while doing insert into table `django_celery_beat_periodictask`

Database is sqlite3. Python version is 3.5.6. All migrations were applied and `django_celery_beat` was added to settings

Calling code:

```
def register_task(task, interval=DEFAULT_TASK_INTERVAL):
    logger.info("Registering periodic task %s with interval %s", task, interval)
    name = "Default {}".format(task)

    schedule, _ = IntervalSchedule.objects.update_or_create(
        every=interval, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS)
    PeriodicTask.objects.update_or_create(
        name=name, defaults={
            "interval": schedule,
            "task": task
        })
```

Actual traceback:

```
File "/home/zab/Git/overview-server/overview-server/src/basis/tasks/shedule.py", line 21, in register_task
    "task": task
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_celery_beat/managers.py", line 14, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self.get_or_create(defaults=defaults, **kwargs)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 489, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 521, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 316, in save
    super(PeriodicTask, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1285, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/zab/venv/overview/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.django_celery_beat_solarschedule__old
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, use clear and descriptive titles to make the question reach more people.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you didn't run `migrate` and as result those tables were not created.

Run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And make sure you added it to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_celery_beat',
)
```

Comment: If I clear the DB and don't run migrations I'm getting errors about tables that were used in query. Main problem here is that I'm getting error about table that was not used in the query. As I know *__old tables are used is django migrations when altering existing tables but not in usual queries.

Comment: thanks bro, I forgot to run the migrations

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Django. Migrations were broken for new sqlite.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182

Answer (score 0):

Bumping for recent answer. I was using the tables before they were migrated. So I commented out all the code involving beat (except installed apps), ran `python manage.py migrate` fresh, then uncommented the code